# Discussing results that follow from : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

The following result is a simple result but I think it reveals some interesting results as consequences.

Given a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of positive integers then the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x_n}$ converges.
Proof is simple. 
In each direction assuming one sum to be convergent we can show the other sum is bounded and since it monotone increases so it must converge.

It has some interesting consequences :
For example 
since we know that the sum of the reciprocal of prime numbers diverges so this result tells us that given any integer $m$ and any integer $k \ge 2$ then there are infinitely many primes not of the form $n^k+m$.

Also from Brun's theorem we know that the sum of the reciprocal of the twin primes converge and hence we can deduce that given any integer $m$ there are infinitely many primes not at a distance of $m$ from some twin prime number.

With other sequences we get other interesting results.

So we can work on better versions of the result and applying it can give us some nice interesting results.

If possible please disucuss about this result and other things that follow from it.